# Deploying logistic regression model with predetermined coefficients in R

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression

I have a logistic regression model with the coefficients already determined and I want to deploy in R.

I know it is extremely simple to just write my own function to do it, but I'm curious if there is some existing functionality that I am missing that's even simpler?

Basically I am looking to use something like the `predict()` functionality of `glm` with my own coefficients rather than fitting the model in R.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use the predict function in R in a logistic regression fitted years ago?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266418/how-can-i-use-the-predict-function-in-r-in-a-logistic-regression-fitted-years-ag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the matrix form to do this:

```
logitp_est <- sum(c(1, values) * coefficients)
```

If you want the probability,

```
prob_est <- 1 / (1 + exp(-1 * logitp_est))
```

or the built in `plogis()`:

```
prob_est <- plogis(logitp_est)
```

If you want the classification:

```
class_est <- logitp_est > 0
```

Comment: or use the built-in `plogis()` for the logistic function

Comment: @BenBolker: good point.  I was in a let's get back to the math mode.

Answer (score 2):

It's not recommended, but you could always change the coefficients by hand.

```
iris2 <- iris[, 1:4]; iris2$dep_var <- as.integer(ifelse(iris2$Sepal.Length > 5, 1, 0))
x <- glm(dep_var ~ ., family = binomial(link = logit), iris2)
x$coefficients
# (Intercept)  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length   Petal.Width
# -1990.9311682   392.5953392     2.0776581     0.5389770     0.9594286
predict(x, iris2[1, ])
#          1
#   19.52332
x$coefficients['Sepal.Length'] <- 393
predict(x, iris2[1, ])
#        1
# 21.58709
```

Note this will likely screw with things like `summary(x)`.